# how to edit and print data segment in emu8086?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

In `debug`, I can use `-e 200` to directly edit data segment, can I do this in `emu8086`?
Does the following work?

```
mov di,200H
mov [di],32H
```

Moreover, I wonder how to view this data in **both hexadecimal and ascii** format (i.e. `32H`(hex) and `2`(ascii))?

Again I can do this with `-d 200` in `debug`, I wonder
is there a single instruction to manage this?

this is what I expect, which is simple to achieve in `debug`
[image]

Comment: Do you want `mov [di],32H` to be a byte or word store?  emu8086 is terrible and assumes one or the other, instead of warning you of the ambiguity, so you should be careful to specify what operand-size you want with something like `mov word ptr [200h], 32h` to store 2 bytes for example, when using `memory, immediate` operands.

Comment: Debuggers implement commands like `e` and `d` with several dozens or hundreds of instructions. To make a hexdump (like `d`) you need to format hexadecimal numbers, and display single bytes verbatim (but you should filter out nonprintables).

Comment: thank both of you very much. I'm pretty sure to continue to use `debug` though... since our course of assembly is about to end haha